# android webview w/o app?

Tags: android, webview, viewport

Im trying to make a website load and look like webview when useing and android device.Im not making and app. really I just need to get rid of the address bar. I have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
```

in the head and the JS window.scroll method will not work.

Comment: Im having the same problem. Hope someone can help.